# Get a separate count for different values in same column

Tags: php, mysql

I want to have separate count for 3 possible values, i.e. `onnet`, `offnet` and `international` in the same column (`type`) for each distinct user.  My table is like this:

```
number      type
03212889438 onnet
03215350700 international
03212889438 offnet
03455919448 international
03215350700 onnet
03212889438 offnet
03455919448 offnet
```

So the sums would be:

```
number      onnet   offnet  international
03212889438 1       2       0
03215350700 1       0       1
03455919448 0       1       1
```

Then I want to display next to each number its type with the highest count:

```
number      highest
03212889438 Offnet
03215350700 Onnet
03455010448 Offnet
```

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: What do you want to display for `highest` in the event of a tie?

Comment: I do get count for each type value separately for each distinct user through 3 queries but thats i thnk looks quite obselete. i want a singl query to serve the purpose,, is there any way? @SalmanA

Comment: Just post whatever you have tried. I am sure someone will correct it or suggest a better solution.

Comment: could be any type value for tie scenario or is it possible to display international if tie is b/w highest and any other value and display onnet when tie is b/w onnet and offnet... please help me out... m quite new to php @eggyal

Comment: @SalmanA,,,, through 3 such queries, i get separate count.. but i need one query and then wants comparision

$r="SELECT  distinct number, count(type) as onnet from calls where type='onnet' group by number";
$d=mysql_query($r); 
while($w=mysql_fetch_array($d))
{
  echo $w['number'];
    echo $w['onnet'] ;}

Answer (score 1):

To get first result you will be required to use pivot table concept as below

```
    SELECT
    number,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'onnet' THEN id ELSE NULL END) AS onnet,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'offnet' THEN id ELSE NULL END) AS offnet,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'international' THEN id ELSE NULL END) AS international
FROM
    test2
GROUP BY
    number;

SELECT   number,
         CASE GREATEST(
           count(type='onnet'),
           count(type='offnet'),
           count(type='international')
         )
           WHEN count(type='onnet')         THEN 'onnet'
           WHEN count(type='offnet')        THEN 'offnet'
           WHEN count(type='international') THEN 'international'
         END AS highest
FROM     test2
GROUP BY number;
```

above query will give you output as required

see [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5441d/3)

Answer (score 1):

You need to *group* your records using a suitable aggregate function; in MySQL one can do:

```sql
SELECT   number,
         SUM(type='onnet')         AS onnet,
         SUM(type='offnet')        AS offnet,
         SUM(type='international') AS international
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY number;

SELECT   number,
         CASE GREATEST(
           SUM(type='onnet'),
           SUM(type='offnet'),
           SUM(type='international')
         )
           WHEN SUM(type='onnet')         THEN 'onnet'
           WHEN SUM(type='offnet')        THEN 'offnet'
           WHEN SUM(type='international') THEN 'international'
         END AS highest
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY number;
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce41a/1).

Comment: i think insted of sum we may need to use count

Comment: Thankyou so much @eggyal.. it works for me.. can u plz guide me further about tie scenario.. i want to display 'international' as highest when tie is between 'international' and any other type and wants to display 'offnet' when tie is b/w offnet and onnet... your help would be really appreciated